# What is --PHP-mixed--?

Tags: php, email

Im sending an email since php code, and it works but after my email i see

```
--PHP-mixed-bbb20c9a2db060ffb76ac37bb00dc754;--
```

what does that mean?

this is my code:

```
   <?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$enlace = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$enlace) {
    die('No se pudo conectar:' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('mybd');
$sqlcot="SELECT * FROM registros";
$resultado=mysql_query($sqlcot,$enlace);

if($resultado === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); 
    echo mysql_error();
}

require_once('dompdf/AttachMailer.php'); 
while ($dato=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{
$nombreinvitado= $dato['nombreinvitado'];

$cuerpo = '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body><div>
<table align="center" width="716">
  <tr align="center">
    <td style="background-color:#E6E6E3"><img src="http://playss.net/email/images/logo.png" alt="Desarrollado para JC Contadores" style="display:block;" width="250" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >

    <table width="714">
  <tr>
    <td width="360" height="363"><img width="360" src="http://playss.net/promo1/images/barreras.png" alt="Logo" style="display:block;"/></td>
    <td width="342" align="justify"> <p style="float:right; padding:20px; text-align:justify; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666">
    <h1 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#8A0E13; ">'.$nombreinvitado.'!</h1>
    <ul style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; padding:10px;">
    <li style="padding-bottom:10px">Queremos agradecer tu presencia a este Networking realizado por JC Surez & CIA y ser parte de este momento tan importante para nuestra firma.</li> 
<li style="padding-bottom:10px">Esperamos que hayas disfrutado este evento.</li>
<li style="padding-bottom:10px">Te invitamos a que ingreses a nuestro sitio web y conozcas acerca de nuestros servicios. <a href="http://www.jcsuarez.com.mx/"><b>www.jcsuarez.com.mx</b></a> </li>
<li style="padding-bottom:10px">Esperamos poder apoyarte en tu proyecto o empresa.</li>
<li style="padding-bottom:10px">Muchas Gracias.</li>

<br/>
<table align="right" >
<tr align="right"> <td>C.P. Julio Cesar Surez</td> </tr>
<tr align="right"> <td>Director General</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right"> <td>JC Surez & CIA</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right"> <td>Contadores Pblicos</td>
</tr>
 </table>
    </ul>
   </p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td style="background-color:#E6E6E3;"><img src="http://playss.net/email/images/wflogo.png" alt="Desarrollado por 3demak.com" style="display:block;" width="200" />
    <table width="600">
  <tr>

  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

';

$email=$dato['correo'];

$mailer = new AttachMailer("myemail@email.com.mx", $email, "Bienvenido ".$nombreinvitado."!", "$cuerpo");

$mailer->send() ? "Enviado": "Problema al enviar";

}
header('Location: indexreg.php?ms=2');
?>
```

**any idea? thank you!**

I can see the images and the text but I dont know why the line is appearing

Comment: Please, unless this is some legacy app from the 1990s, don't use `mysql_query` in new code.

Answer (score 3):

That's a boundary string. It really could be any string, but email send applications use it to know where different sections of the email (plain text, html) begin and end.

Comment: How I can do to avoid that line? @JakeParis

Comment: It's part of the MIME standard.

Comment: I tryied with lines like `$cuerpo.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";` But it doesn't work... Some idea? I don't wanna show that line

Comment: @user4220812, you're not understanding. That line will not show in anyone's email. Here's what you should do. Open up an email in your favorite client and "show original" (in gmail, similar in other clients). and you will see all the headers & boundary strings that are part of the email that don't get shown. I think then you will understand more what is going on here.